# Dual norm only for a part of matrix

Tags: normed-spaces, tensor-products, quantum-information, dual-cone

A dual norm $\|\cdot\|^\circ$ of norm $\|\cdot\|$ can be given in terms of inner product
$$\|A\|^\circ=\max_B |\text{Tr}(AB)|,$$
with the constraint $\|B\|\leq1$. This can be re-expressed, for unitarily invariant norms, as
$$\|A\|^\circ=\max_B\|AB\|_1,$$
where $\|X\|_1=\text{Tr}(\sqrt{X^\dagger X})$ is the trace norm.
Can this notion of dual norm can be extended to partial trace of bipartite operator? In other words, is there well developed results for the following maximization
$$\max_B \|A(I\otimes B)\|_1,$$
where $\|B\| \leq1$? For example, $\|B\|$ can be Schatten-$p$ norm.